# How to give Json input in object type rather than array type?

Tags: json

From c#, I need to send a JSON format input with object instead of array. I do have JSON format in array type. Below is the example of my requirement.

Array type JSON Format:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "LogicalName": "Project",
    "Attributes": [
      {"a":"1"},
      {"b":"1"}
    ]
  },
  "Project Items": {
     "LogicalName": "ProjectItems",
    "Attributes": [
      {"c":"1"},
      {"d":"1"}
    ]
  }
}
```

I need like this, Object type JSON format:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "LogicalName": "Project",
    "Attributes": {
      "A":{"a":"1"},
      "B":{"b":"1"}
    }
  },
  "Project Items": {
     "LogicalName": "ProjectItems",
    "Attributes": {
      "C":{"c":"1"},
      "D":{"d":"1"}
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this in c#?